# How do I transform Apache Ignite Java Based Config to Spring XML Config?

Tags: java, spring, ignite

How would I transform below ignite Java Config to Spring XML Config given below ?

[image]

Comment: here is Sample :

Comment: <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
    <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
    <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
        <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 4GB. -->
        <property name="maxSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as the accepted one if it has solved your issue ?

Comment: This is still missing-- setDataRegionConfiuration(new .........

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above Java config in Spring XML Config is given below :

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
      <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="maxSize" value="#{45L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="name" value="cold"/> 
          </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```